# Why using a class as a variable member inside that said class

Tags: java, class, variables, instance-variables

I am new to Java and been studying it. So I am having trouble to understand what are these and how it being processed by Java also why are we declaring these variables like that. I mean can you educate me on this?

```
Public abstract class ListItem {
    protected Listitem leftLink = null;
    protected Listitem rightLink = null;
    protected Object value;

    some code here
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are seeing here are fields which are one of class members. Anyway you need to be more specific about what is confusing you. What is not clear about it in Java tutorial/book you read? Have you seen https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is vague. Yes, I had done OOP and understand it well. To make my question clear, I am confused on why declare a Class field which has the ClassName as variable type instead of a int, string etc.

Comment: Because you want to store data of that type, and not an int, string, etc.

Comment: That's what confused me, why declare your variable type of a Class? How it works when you are using it in other Class or on your main Class?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why declare a Class field which has the ClassName as variable type instead of a int, string... ?**

Because the developer needs to. Sometimes, an instance of a class must reference another instance of the same class. A typical example is the LinkedList.

Consider a linked list as a sequence of nodes. Each node knows the next one to be linked. Here would be a naive implementation of a node:

```
class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> next;
    private T value;

    Node(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class `Node` contains a variable member of type `Node`, to reference the next element of the linked list. Finally, a simplistic implementation of the linked list would be:

```
class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> first;
    private Node<T> last;
    private int length = 0;

    public void add(T value) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);

        if(length != 0) {
            last.setNext(node);
            last = node;
        }
        else {
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }

        length++;
    }

    public Node<T> getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
}
```

When a new node is added to the collection, the *previous last* node references it and therefore, becomes the *new last* node.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to elaborate things to me and this did help me to understand it. Though I do not have fully understand it this will be my stepping stone to further understand things with Java or OOP.

Comment: In fact, you don't have any constraint that would prevent you to use a class inside itself, as a reference. Another example would be a class `Person`. Let's reasonably assume a person has a mother and a father. Those two parents are `Person`s as well! :) Thus, the class `Person` can declare a variable member of type `Person` to reference his/her mother. I kindly remind you to mark your question as answered if you feel this answer is adequate.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a a lot.